# Почему не срабатывает replace? замена не проводится

Tags: javascript, html, match, replace

> getParams['smartname']="'Слово'";

```
found = getParams['smartname'].replace(new RegExp("'",'g'),"123");
    document.write(decodeURIComponent(found));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте вот так:

```
found = getParams['smartname'].replace("'","");
```

Comment: @Breaker
%27%D0%92%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%27
почему тогда такой результат?

Comment: @Анатолийй буквы потому что русские :)

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов тогда какой вариант подойдет и под русские?

Comment: пробуйте decodeURIComponent()

Comment: и, да, покажите код, который выдает вам такой результат.

Comment: подозреваю, что вам нужно что-то типа такого:

getParams['smartname'] = decodeURIComponent(getParams['smartname']);
found = getParams['smartname'].replace("'","");
document.write(found);

P.S. Я могу ошибаться.